# How to update the value of progressbar and textblock in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, progress-bar, busyindicator

I'm new to wpf and c# and also in asking here. I am searching the web for hours and i haven't found a solution for my problem. I have a progress bar that updates it's value whenever the loop increments and a textblock that updates it's text (ex: Reading Lines 5/3000). Currently, I don't have the binding path so i make a dummy binding in my xaml. I don't know exactly how to make it work.

Here's my XAML:

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator x:Name="_busyIndicator" Grid.Row="4">
                <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="4">
                            <TextBlock Text="Parsing OTM File" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            <StackPanel Margin="4">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberOfLinesOfStringInTextFile}" />
                                <ProgressBar Grid.Row="4" Name="prgParse" Height="15" Value="{Binding CurrentLineNumberAddedToListView}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
                <xctk:BusyIndicator.OverlayStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#ffffeeee"/>
                    </Style>
                </xctk:BusyIndicator.OverlayStyle>
                <xctk:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Style>
                </xctk:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
                <ListBox x:Name="_listBox" />
            </xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

I have a button that triggers the loop that reads the lines inside the text file (in this case it has 3000+ lines) and places the line of string to the listview. I want to update the textblock in my xaml that states "Reading Lines 300/3000" and the progressbar indicating it's percentage which updates its value to 10 or 10% while it is transferring the data to the listview.

Here is my code behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

        }

        private void cmdBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var OpenOTM = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            OpenOTM.DefaultExt = ".otm";
            OpenOTM.Filter = "OTM Files (*.otm)|*.otm|TEXT Files (*.txt)|*.txt"; 

            if (OpenOTM.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault(false))
            {
                txtFilePath.Text = OpenOTM.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void cmdOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WithAdjustments wa = new WithAdjustments();
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(txtFilePath.Text);
            worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
            {
                List<String> listOfString = new List<string>();
                foreach (string lin in lines)
                {
                    listOfString.Add(lin);
                    Thread.Sleep(2);
                }

                Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => _listBox.ItemsSource = listOfString));
            };
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
            {
                _busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
            };
            _busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance! I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Update your properties CurrentLineNumberAddedToListView, NumberOfLinesOfStringInTextFile using Background Worker report progress callback,

```
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

worker.ProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
{
     //Here in e.ProgressPercentage you will get the current line number read you can deduct the textblock text and progressbar value to be set on CurrentLineNumberAddedToListView and NumberOfLinesOfStringInTextFile
}

worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
        {
            List<String> listOfString = new List<string>();
            BackgroundWorker worker = o as BackgroundWorker;
            int numberofLine = 0;
            foreach (string lin in lines)
            {
                listOfString.Add(lin);

                o.ReportProgress(++numberofLine);
                Thread.Sleep(2);
            }


            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => _listBox.ItemsSource = listOfString));
        };
```

Comment: hi sir @nit i'm totally and literally a noob here, i'm sorry but i didn't understand or i don't know how to do this "//Here in e.ProgressPercentage you will get the current line number read you can deduct the textblock text and progressbar value to be set on CurrentLineNumberAddedToListView and NumberOfLinesOfStringInTextFile". BTW, thank you so much for giving me an idea :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you with your ProgressBar:

```
Private Sub InitProgressBar(ByVal DblMaximumValueI As Double)
    'set min and max
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = DblMaximumValueI
    'set start value
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
End Sub

Private Sub IncremenetProgressBar_()
    ProgressBar1.Value += 1 'or variable
End Sub
```

and call sub below to show progress:

```
Public Sub IncrementProgressBar()
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, New Action(AddressOf IncremenetProgressBar_))
End Sub
```

and to update your TextBlock you could add a module like:

```
Module ExtensionMethods
'anonymous delegates are not allowed in VB.NET, so we need an empty method
Private Sub EmptyMethod()

End Sub

'refresh for Controls
<Extension()> _
Public Sub Refresh(ByVal uiElement As UIElement)
    uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, New Action(AddressOf EmptyMethod))
End Sub

End Module
```

and then call TextBloxName.Refresh after setting the TextBloxName.Text

Comment: I hate to downvote, but the question is in C# and this is a .vb answer.

Comment: Oh thank you. So you downvote me because I tried to help and I am not able to write c#? Do you think that no answer is better then one in an other language!? Or should I ask somebody to translate it for me? What do other people think about this? I would be happy to recieve an C# answer even if I don't know this language good.